# Excel: Reference a formula in a cell from another worksheet where rows are added

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

help is appreciated on this topic!

- I am trying to reference cell B10 from Sheet2 to cell A1 in Sheet1.
- Cell B10 contains the formula `SUM(B1:OFFSET(B10,-1,0))`, which sums values from B1:B9.
- Daily, I add a new row to Sheet2 such that the Column B range increases by +1, from B1:B9 to B1:B10, and the formula from B10 moves to B11.
- I now need cell A1 in Sheet1 to reference cell B11 in Sheet2.

I've tried using offset() and indirect() but haven't figured this out.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to handle this:

1) Every time you insert the row, make sure you place your cursor on the formula cell before manually inserting row. If you do, the formula in `Sheet1!A1` will automatically follow suit, and you can add whatever you need in the new cell (created from the new row). For example, inserting a row at `B10` will adjust the formula in `A1` to say `=Sheet2!B11`.

2) Realizing that point 1 may not be suitable to your process, place this formula in `Sheet1A1`: `=OFFSET(Sheet2!B1,COUNT(Sheet2!B1:B100)-1,0)` 
 You can adjust the `B100` to whatever you need. Just be sure there's nothing in between the the final formula cell and the last row in the this formula range.

Comment: I tried recommendation #1 but was unable to achieve the desired result. However, rec #2 works perfectly! Thank you :)